# Is there a way to autotab the pdf fields in Acrobat/ IE, apart from the js in the pdf?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, plugins, acrobat, ieaddon

I have a pdf with multiple fields to be filled by opening in IE/Acrobat only. I need to autotab all the fields in the pdf once, to achieve my objective. 
So, can an IE add-on or something else can automate the autotab on the pdf fields apart from writing JS in the field? Please provide with suggestions.

Comment: There's a bit of plumbing involved but it is possible. You can't link directly to the PDF, instead, create an HTML page and then use the <object> tag to embed the PDF which can take 100% of the window. The reason you need to do this is so you can create a JavaScript "message" handler in the browser. The embedded PDF can then communicate with the HTML host. And the host can send instructions into the PDF. See the linked docs.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FHostContainer.htm

Comment: thnx dude, but i can't get the iframe element by id in selenium,

Comment: Don't use an iframe. Use an Object tag to embed the PDF in the HTML.

Comment: But object tag doesnt works in ie, so i resorted to iframe

Comment: I'm fairly certain it does but try the embed tag instead if the iframe.